# Maintaining and escaping single quotes in custom dimensions Google Analytics

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I have a custom dimension in Universal Analytics where I am passing the value of the alt attribute to it and it works perfectly except when the alt attribute string contains a single quote.Here is the code.

```
formattedString = "<a href='" + iconUrl + "' title='" + urlTitle + "' target='_blank' alt='" + title + "'><img class='gird-icon' src='images/datatable-icon.gif'/></a>";
var downloadtitle = (typeof (el.attr('alt')) != 'undefined') ? el.attr('alt') : '';
ga('set', 'dimension1', downloadtitle);
```

If my alt attribute has this. The Nation's peace.

It comes out like this. The Nation
dropping everything after the single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by doing this.

```
title = title.replace(/'/g, "\&#39;");
```

I suspect GA uses an html coded Character set. This site did the conversion.
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/jsexamples/syntax/prepareInline.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap the last parameter in double quotes like this:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', '"'+downloadtitle+'"');
```

This puts double quotes around that string and does not evaluate the single quote contained within.

Comment: Hi Nicky, that did not help. Here is what I changed my code to.

ga('set', 'dimension1', '"'+downloadtitle+'"');
Nation's Peace (expected)

"Nation" (what I get)

Can I wrap download title in some jQuery method?


ga('set', 'dimension1', jQueryMethod(downloadtitle));

Comment: I'm not too sure why you would have this problem. I've tried it out myself and everything seems to be working as expected. You can try to use escapeURI(downloadtitle).

Comment: would I do something like this?

Comment: ga('set', 'dimension1', escapeURI(downloadtitle));